# .gitignore ignoring some Intellij Idea files but not others

Tags: git

Intellij Idea generates project-specific files. Before I did any git add or git commit or git push. I wanted to make sure that certain files were not included in git version control:

```
# Ignore Intellij Idea project-specific files.
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/dictionaries/*
```

The workspace.xml was successfully not included in the repository. However, a file under .idea/dictionaries/ was: `.idea/dictionaries/myprojectname.xml`

Why was this specific file not ignored by git?

Comment: The file should have been ignored.  But did you already add this file previously?  Why  was it showing up in the first place?

Comment: No I did not already add the file previously. It is showing up because Intellij Idea generates it but it should be available on my machine but not in git or to other users. I ended up having to do this: git rm --cached -r .idea/dictionaries

Comment: If you needed to do this then it means that those IntelliJ files were already committed to the repository, and adding them to `.gitignore` should not have worked.

Comment: may be useful: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/7d201a5b7920898e36af7463f30ac5d90eea9942/Global/JetBrains.gitignore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper syntax to ignore a folder content is:

```
.idea/dictionaries/
```

To check if a file is ignored or not, type:

```
git check-ignore -v -- .idea/dictionaries/myprojectname.xml
```

If the result is empty, it is not ignored.

> I ended up having to do this: git rm --cached -r .idea/dictionaries

The file was already added and committed before you made the .gitignore.